# LDAP Add User (Authentication)

Tags: openldap

I have installed OpenLDAP server.

How to add user (entry) in LDAP server. And how to open command window for that server, so that I can run the ldap command on it:

:
My requirement is : in my app i want to authenticate users which are added in Openldap server
but i am only able to install OpenLDAP server on windows os,, but how to add the user i unable to get the way. what is the way to add user in openLDAP whic is install on windows 7 OS? this is what i want to ask

Answer (score 0):

You can add entries to the LDAP database in several ways. While slapd is running you can use ldapadd/ldapmodify to add entries.   You can also use slapadd with an ldif file as well.

Read up on the usage of these tools and then come back with any question you may have afterwards.

You also need to understand how to construct a directory information tree in order to give some structure to the data you are storing in the LDAP database.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily by using LDAPAdmin